# How to get clickable selected text from WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing an android application. I want highlight the text when a word selected from a `WebView`. It also able to selected a text when it(`WebView`) clickable. But i do not get the selected text from the `WebView`.

**My code:**

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setLongClickable(true);

webView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
{                       
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
    {
         return false;
    } 
});
```

Comment: If i understand your question correctly you want to know clickable item in webView ? than answer for that question lies in Hybrid approach : you have to write logic in JavaScript embedded in HTML page and by code you can identify the clickable item and if you want to call native api than you can use HTML5 capabilities to launch that approach.

Answer (score 1):

To select text from `WebView` you can use..

```
    public void SelectText(){  
    try{  
      KeyEvent shiftPressEvent =   
               new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,       
               KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);  
      shiftPressEvent.dispatch(myWebView);  
  }catch(Exception e){  
      throw new AssertionError(e);  
  }
```

Where,below 2 lines will be on your `OnCreate()`:

```
WebView myWebView;
myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);  
myWebView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522578/how-to-get-clickable-selected-text-from-webview");
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail. Because I didn't get exactly how do I get selected text from webview long press. Any idea?  Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I tried but not understand the code. Could you please show selected text in toast or log it. !!! Thanks.